c++ gmp(mpz_cmp) giving incorrect answer?
im writing a program in c++ using GMP and im getting incorrect results.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "gmpxx.h"

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int mytest2 = 0;
    int mytest= 0;  
    std::string myoutputstr = "";

    mpz_t myfilter,myfilter2, myzero;
    mpz_inits(myfilter,myfilter2, myzero, NULL);

    mpz_t xtemp, startx;
    mpz_inits(xtemp, startx, NULL);

    mpz_set_str(myfilter, "1000000", 16);
    mpz_set_str(myfilter2, "c000000", 16);
    mpz_set_str(startx, "b5161710f16f64abf4b45070bf9d360b8b1e562e3218decf74a9b754dc000000", 16);
    mpz_set_str(myzero, "0", 16);

    std::string tempstr = "";

            mpz_mod(xtemp, startx, myfilter2);

                mytest2 = mpz_cmp(xtemp, myzero);

                if (mytest2 == 0)
                {
                    tempstr = mpz_out_str(NULL, 16, startx);
                    std::cout << tempstr << " xsum1\n"; // this should execute 
                }
            tempstr = mpz_out_str(NULL, 16, startx);
            std::cout << tempstr << " xsum\n";  

}

This if statement should be true unless im misunderstanding it. Im using VS 2022 on windows 10. I have shortened this down to a sample that shows incorrect response.

startx mod myfilter2 gives 0x8000000, not zero. So the statement is not true. Just using the same digits on the end doesn't make it divisible by that value.

Well asked question but your understanding of division is faulty. Incidentally mpz_sgn(xtemp) == 0 is a more efficient way to test for zero.

Thank you for the quick responses both pointing out my error. I can't hardly believe I missed that. Now I have to figure out how to determine if it does end With "c000000" as that's what I was looking for.

@JoshWert A bitwise-and with 0xFFFFFFF and then test if that equals 0xC000000 will do that,

It's safer to use boost.multiprecission with gmp backend. Boost provides C++ big number classes with 3 different backends. It has less caveats due to hiding memory management chores from user code.

John. i really appetite that, Now I can get back to testing the prototype code before rewriting it in opencl, already have it in cuda((that works correctly) but need it to work on AMD GPUs.
Brett - Thank you for pointing out my math error I forgot that only works with 000s when modding by a hex starting with 1 followed by 0s
Red Wave - thank you for the suggestion but as this was, hopefully, the last bug in this before a rewrite using opencl I would prefer not to change it now unless boost will help with opencl version
